# Update of first two letter or mark as null if empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

Forced update of first letters if present else mark it as null when empty

```
IF LENGTH([Column])>0 THEN UPDATE [Table] SET Position = Upper([Column]) ELSE RETURN NULL END IF;
```

```
Col A
abcdef
defghi
efgijg
''
elllef
''
ijkmnk
```

Expected Result (first two as capital and marked as null if row value is empty)

```
Col A
ABcdef
DEfghi
EFgijg
NULL
ELllef
NULL
IJkmnk
```

Comment: So, what is the question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: IF LENGTH([Column])>0 THEN
   UPDATE  [Table] SET Position = Upper([Column])
ELSE
    RETURN NULL
END IF;

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `CASE` expression in the SET part

```
UPDATE the_table
  SET column_a = CASE 
                   WHEN column_a = '' THEN NULL
                   ELSE upper(left(column_a,2))||substr(column_a,3)
                 END;
```

If you want to treat a value with only spaces as "empty" as well, you can use `WHEN trim(column_a) = '' THEN NULL` instead.